# Unexpected end of input, jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I get the following error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input` for line 1.

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./styles/default.css" />
<script src="./scripts/global.js"></script>
<script src="./scripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
var array = [ 'body_bg_2','body_bg_3','body_bg_4','body_bg_5' ];
    var selected = array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
    $('<img src="./assets/'+selected+'.gif">').load(function() {
      $(this).appendTo('body');
    });
}
</script>
<title>Cats!</title>
</head>
```

I don't understand what the issue is? Anyone know of the solution?

Comment: Well, you miss at least a `);` at the end of your script. Which is opened by `.ready(`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about syntax error. Stackoverflow is not a debugging help desk...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing closing `)` of your document-ready handler

Use

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
var array = [ 'body_bg_2','body_bg_3','body_bg_4','body_bg_5' ];
    var selected = array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
    $('<img src="./assets/'+selected+'.gif">').load(function() {
      $(this).appendTo('body');
    });
}); //<== Here you have missed )
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var array = [ 'body_bg_2', 'body_bg_3', 'body_bg_4', 'body_bg_5' ];
    var selected = array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
    $('<img src="./assets/' + selected + '.gif">').load(function () {
        $(this).appendTo('body');
    });
}); /* <--- this is your fail */
```